# Custom DataSource Extender

Tags: asp.net, datasource, dataview

I dream of creating a control which works something like this:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource
      id="dsFoo"
      runat="server"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conn %>"
      SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
      SelectCommand="cmd_foo">
 </asp:SqlDataSource>

<Custom:DataViewSource
     id="dvFoo"
     runat="server"
     rowfilter="colid &gt; 10"
     datasourceid="dsFoo">
</Custom:DataViewSource>
```

I can accomplish the same thing in the code behind by executing `cmd_foo`, loading the results into a `DataTable`, then loading them into a `DataView` with a `RowFilter`.  The goal would be to have multiple `DataView`s for one `DataSource` with whatever special filters I wish to apply to the select portion of the `DataSource`.  I could imagine extending this to be more powerful.

I tried peaking at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms391944(VS.80).aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.aspx) but am a bit confused on a few points.

Currently, my main issue is being unsure where to grab the output data of the `DataSource` so I can stick it into a `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I was stuck at:

```
DataView dv = dsFoo.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty) as DataView;
DataTable dt = dv.ToTable()
```

The second line is likely unnecessary since the original goal was to turn a `DataSource` into a `DataView`.

Of course, looking up this stuff tells me that `SqlDataSource` already has `FilterExpression`...